# jQuery slide toggle shows then disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRJEwx

So basically jQuery toggle 'slide' slides the div in and then right back out. It only happens every second or third time you press the button. It never happens on the first try but seems to happen on the second or third try after clicking the back button.

```js
$('#go').on('click', function() {
  $('#s1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#s2').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 800, function() {

      $('#s2 .back').on('click', function() {
        $('#s2').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $('#s1').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
          }, 800);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  background: gray;
  height: 400px;
}

#s1,
#s2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#s1 {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: purple;
}

#s2 {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  background: blue;
}

#s3 {
  display: none;
  background: black;
}

#go,
#go2 {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
}

.back {
  background: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s1">
  <div id="go">GO TO SCREEN2</div>
</div>
<div id="s2">
  <div class="back">GO BACK</div>
</div>
```

So essentially it's working right the first time. But the second time it shows the second screen and then immediately hides. Any idea how I can get it to slide and then stay put until the back button is pressed?

Comment: *pro tip* Move `$('#s2 .back').on` out of click event. Now you create new event every time you click on `$('#go')`

Comment: protip #2: the SO snippet editor is really good, and saves making people waste time by going off site.

Comment: @Justinas that worked thanks. Do I need to move $('#s2 .back').on out of $('#go').on entirely? Or just outside of $('#s2').toggle?

Comment: @Mia I have provided answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the second on click event listener as a callback to the first one.
Unnest them so they sit at the same depth in the code:

```
$('#go').on('click', function(){
                    $('#s1').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                        $('#s2').toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 800);
                    });
                });

$('#s2 .back').on('click', function(){
                                $('#s2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                                    $('#s1').toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 800);
                                });
                            });
```

Comment: and nothing is being added dynamically in your example so @Justinas point on dynamic elements is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

You are binding new `#s2 .back` click event every time you click on `#go`. Move it out of click event.

Also please not how `.on` is working. It must be binded to static element, so it's form is `$(staticElement).on(event, dynamicElement, callback)`. So if your `#go` is some time will be removed and added using JS, than your provided form will not work.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#go', function() {
  $('#s1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#s2').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 800);
  });
});


$(document).on('click', '#s2 .back', function() {
  $('#s2').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#s1').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 800);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  background: gray;
  height: 400px;
}

#s1,
#s2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#s1 {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: purple;
}

#s2 {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  background: blue;
}

#s3 {
  display: none;
  background: black;
}

#go,
#go2 {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
}

.back {
  background: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="s1">
  <div id="go">GO TO SCREEN2</div>
</div>
<div id="s2">
  <div class="back">GO BACK</div>
</div>
```